# how to stop a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, input

I wrote this code that I'm trying to get it to work. What I am trying to do is to prompt user to enter names of employees and use a list to store the names.

Now the part that I am having trouble with is with the loop, the loop is suppose to stop when the user types 'done', and then display the number of names entered, and with another loop, display the names entered each on its own line.

I don't know what I am doing wrong with the code but, after the user enters then names it will say: 'Press enter to continues adding names' and it will also say: 'If you would like to stop adding names, type=done'

If the user hits enter, then it should ask for another name and repeat the questions to see if user wants to add more or stop. But for some reason, even if the user press enter to continue adding names, it still outputs the number of names entered and the list of names. I don't want that to happen, I'm trying to get it to where it will display the result ONLY if the user types 'done' but the word 'done, cannot be displayed in the output. I've looked over and over the code and can't figure out what if am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
employee_list=[]

stop='done'

while stop == 'done':

    employee_name=input('Enter name of employee:')

    employee_list.append(employee_name)

    print('Press enter to continues adding names')

    enter_another=input('If you would like to stop adding names, type=done  ')

      print()

    list_size=len(employee_list)

    print('The number of employees you have entered: ', list_size)

    for index in range(list_size):
        print(employee_list[index])
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got a check in your code if a person types `done`.

For example:

```
if enter_another == "done":
    stop == "finished now"
```

But this doesn't make sense, your check is saying "if stop is done then keep going", which makes no sense semantically.

Try this instead:

```
more_employees = True
while more_employees: # Never do thing == True
    # ... your code

    enter_another=input('If you would like to stop adding names, type=done  ')

    if enter_another == "done":
        more_employees = False

    # ... the rest of your code
```

As stated, [PEP8 recommends against comparing `thing == True`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.
>
> ```
> Yes:   if greeting:
> No:    if greeting == True:
> Worse: if greeting is True:
> ```

Comment: I tried but all I keep getting is: 'If you would like to stop adding names, type=done  
it repeats every time i hit enter.

Comment: Whoops, that should be `more_employees = False`. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: thank you for helping. Tried it, got an error :                if enter_another == "done":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'enter_another' referenced before assignment

Comment: You've put the check before the assignment.

Comment: thank you again for helping, i really appreciate it. Sadly is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have put your printing condition outside the loop.

```
employee_list=[]
stop='done'

while stop == 'done':
    employee_name=raw_input('Enter name of employee: ')

    employee_list.append(employee_name)

    print 'Press enter to continue adding names'

    enter_another=raw_input('If you would like to stop adding names, type=done  \n')

    if enter_another == 'done': 
        stop = 'random'

print 
list_size=len(employee_list)
print 'The number of employees you have entered: ', list_size

for index in range(list_size):
    print employee_list[index],
```